# Change application's starting dart file in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new for flutter and I want to change the starting UI(interface). I tried to find out . but could not do it

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the home: parameter specifies the starting page. If you want to change the page that will open at startup, you can give the name of the page you want instead of HomePage ().

```
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Time Tracker',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
        ),
        home: HomePage(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So:

```
home: HomePage(),
```

Change to:

```
home: AnythingPage()
```